# How to change hidden _token value of an html form data with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

The main problem which I want to fix is the session expiration problem.
I use ajax to send login formData to server.
I use Laravel 5.4.
The form has an hidden element with _token value.
I have two ajaxes. The first one sends request to server which must bring back a new csrf token and the second one sends serialized login formdata.
I checked. The server successfully sends the needed new token value.
But the recommendations from google which I found change the  element's csrf-token value.
But the ajax don't want to send that value, he is sending only _token value, not csrf-token.
I used the

```
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{csrf_token()}}",
},
```

still no effect.
I also tried this one

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

No result.

Interesting fact. When I reload the page with mouse click on browsers reload button the both csrf tokens are being updated, but when I write location.reload in ajax only csrf-token value is being changed. The _token value still the old value.

I even tried to make nested ajaxes, so after the location.reload it tries to send a request to server with the new token. But... anyway. It still send the same old token.

I have a not professional, low quality variant of solution: Change the needed value using the serialized string. I mean, cut the needed part of that string and put the part with the new value.
But I leave it as a last solution if nothing else I can find in future.

So what types of solutions you know or just some hints that may be helpful?

Comment: could you add your full ajax code that you send request from, and what is the error you got in the console?

Comment: @Joseph I solved my problem and put the answer below. You can check it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and fixed it. The one thing I forgot to do was to use

```
$('input[name="_token"]').attr('value', result.token);
```

instead of

```
$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content', result.token);
```

here's the full ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/"+lang+"/refreshToken",
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        console.log('New csrf token === ' + result.token)
        $('input[name="_token"]').attr('value', result.token);

        var loginForm = $("#login-form");
        var formData = loginForm.serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/' + lang + '/signin',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,

            success: function (data) {
                console.log(formData);
                if (payment_login) {
                    var total = parseInt($('#your_total').html());
                    if (data < total) {
                        var mess = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade in balanceIssue"> ' +
                            '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">' +
                            '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>' + $('#lang-notenoughmoney').val() + ' </div>';
                        $('.alert_messige').html(mess);
                        $('.submitPay').attr('data-original-title', $('#lang-notenoughmoney').val());
                        if (!$('.submitPay').hasClass('disabled')) {
                            $('.submitPay').addClass('disabled');
                        }
                        $('#sell-modal').show();
                        $('#signin-modal').hide();

                    } else {
                        sendPayment();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                if (interchange) {
                    window.location.href = '/' + lang + '/interchange';
                    return false;
                }
                if (addAdvert) {
                    window.location.href = '/' + lang + '/add-adverts';
                } else {
                    //location.reload();
                    location.href = '/' + lang + '/privacy';
                }
            },

            error: function (data, err) {
                $('.loginLoading').remove();
                try {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.responseText);

                    if (obj.email) {
                        $('#login-email').addClass('has-error');
                        $('#login-errors-email').html(obj.email);
                    }
                    if (obj.password) {
                        $('#login-password').addClass('has-error');
                        $('#login-errors-password').html(obj.password);
                    }
                    if (obj.verify) {
                        $('#login-email').addClass('has-error');
                        $('#login-errors-email').html(obj.verify);
                    }
                } catch (Exception) {
                    console.log('Sorry, but the responseText cannot be parsed into js object. The server sent you an html code with status code ' + data.status);
                    //location.href = '/'+lang+'/signin';
                    //location.reload();
                }
            }
        })
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```